# shorthand properties and method of css

Tags: html, css

I found someone's jsfiddle containing css like this

```
float: left;
text:{
    decoration: none;
    shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(black, .35);
  }
```

I assume decoration is text-decoration and shadow is text-shadow in `text:`. I want to know more about it what are the other shorthand properties like decoration inside the text? And what are the shorthand methods like `text:` ?

Comment: I'd suggest reading: "[CSS shorthand properties](http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/css-shorthand-properties.shtml)." But that notation suggests they're using LESS or SASS. Can you link to the Fiddle?

Comment: this doesn't look like valid css - did the fiddle work? I don't know SASS, but it's certianly not LESS

Comment: http://codepen.io/roygbiv/pen/FjLcA

Comment: that is SCSS (indicated in the CSS tab header)

Comment: ... and not jsFiddle.

Comment: sorry, my mistake that to say code pen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://sass-lang.com

> Sass avoids repetition by nesting selectors within one another. **The
>   same thing works with properties.**

```
table.hl {
  margin: 2em 0;
  td.ln {
    text-align: right;
  }
}

li {
  font: {
    family: serif;
    weight: bold;
    size: 1.2em;
  }
}
```

which compiles to:

```
/* CSS */

table.hl {
  margin: 2em 0;
}
table.hl td.ln {
  text-align: right;
}

li {
  font-family: serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```